after reset a black screen showed and i can do nothing on the VM
The black screen says:
ata1 master: VBOX CD-ROM ATAPI-6 CD-ROM/DVD-ROM      
PXE-E06: Option ROM requires DDIM support

What can I do?

You've provided no details on what OS you're using...for either your host or guest. Please update/edit with this information.

Root cause:
A Virtual Machine (VM), which has a bootable CD available for it.
Remedy:
Eject the CD or CD-disk-image so that the VM does not see it.
Possible Alternative cause & remedy:
The CD-drive is "broken"; Make sure to disable and remove the emulated CD device; then add/create a new one.
Boot the VM, mount VBxoGuestAdditions.iso "in" the CD-drive, and run a reinstallation of it.
